# Android database method was called twice

Tags: android, sqlite

Could someone please help me with the error I got? I really couldn't figure out why the addCategory() method was called twice which then cause the "UNIQUE constraint failed" problem. Thanks so much. The code are below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
MyDatabase mdb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     mdb=new MyDatabase(this);
     mdb.addCategory("hello");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

and in Mydatabase

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Event24";
public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists test2 
(     " +
            " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " categorys TEXT UNIQUE)" ;
      db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORY_TABLE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int  
newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS events");
    // create fresh books table
    this.onCreate(db);
}

public void addCategory(String name){
    Log.e("mydatabase","addCategory");
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("categorys", name);
    db.insert("test2", // table
            null,  //nullColumnHack
            cv); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values = 
  column values
    db.close();

}

}
```

and the error are below:

```
  05-22 09:50:34.672    1884-1884/com.example.julia.testactivitydatabase E/mydatabase﹕ addCategory
  05-22 09:50:53.135    1884-1884/com.example.julia.testactivitydatabase E/mydatabase﹕ addCategory
  05-22 09:50:53.137    1884-1884/com.example.julia.testactivitydatabase E/SQLiteLog﹕ (2067) abort at 12 in [INSERT INTO test2(categorys) VALUES (?)]: UNIQUE constraint failed: test2.categorys
  05-22 09:50:53.137    1884-1884/com.example.julia.testactivitydatabase E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting categorys=hello
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: test2.categorys (code 2067)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1471)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
        at com.example.julia.testactivitydatabase.MyDatabase.addCategory(MyDatabase.java:54)
        at com.example.julia.testactivitydatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3912)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Looks like you'd get this error just by running your app twice...

Comment: but how could I run it twice if I just click the "run" icon just one time?

Answer (score 1):

Activity.onCreate will be executed every time when the app is launched or screen is rotated. This call is used to create user interface and not tackle DB initialization. This means that it WILL be called not twice but many more times.

If you need to setup some pre-existing categories ONCE, do this in the MyDatabase.onCreate method.

As for "why called twice" - put a log in there. It is not necessary that it was called twice in a row in a single app launch. If you launch the app once, the DB row will be created. If you start it second time, even if onCreate is called once (as it should) during this second launch, the DB will have this fixed unique record from previous start. After all, the purpose of DB is to *persist* information across launches.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was solved by initial database data in the MyDatabase.Oncreate as in your indication. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Please, select answer as solution, so that people know it is solved